# validate whether continuous weekdays checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have checkboxes like below which shows all the days of a week.

[image]

The value of checkboxes are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 respectively.

I need to have a validation logic in javascript which validates whether the user clicks the checkboxes which are continuous days. The continuous days can start from any day. Like,

Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday (4,5,6,7,1)

Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday(2,3,4,5,6,7)

Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday(7,1,2,3,4,5)

Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday(3,4,5,6,7,1)
etc.

Minimum of 5 days should be selected. The user should not be allowed to select like below examples:

Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Wednesday, Thursday(7,1,2,4,5)

Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday(2,4,5,6,7)

Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday(3,5,6,7,1)

Is there any way to handle this validation in javascript/jquery?

Comment: can you share the html of checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the selected values into an array then

```
function test(values){

    if(values.length !=5 ){
        return false;
    }

    var expected = values[0], valid = true;
    $.each(values, function(i, v){
        if( expected != v){
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
        expected  = v == 7 ? 1 : v + 1;
    })

    if(!valid){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9asD/)

Comment: Thanks @Arun for this simple and logical answer. Your solution works fine. But populating the array troubles me. If we select sun, wed, thur, fri, sat(which is correct order) and if we use $.each it will return 1,4,5,6,7 instead of 4,5,6,7,1. Then this solution will not work. Is there a way to populate the array as we need using $.each?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
var checkgroup=checkgroup
var limit=limit
for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
    var checkedcount=0
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
    if (checkedcount>limit){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
        this.checked=false
        }
    }
}
 }
```

ADD THIS IN BODY SECTION

```
  checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, 2) // here 2 states to select only two check box
```